# 3rd Party Android Markets

Tags: android

Does anyone use any of the 3rd party Android markets for publishing their apps? What is your take on these? Are they credible? Of course I will keep my apps in the standard Android Market, but just wondering is I should use a 3rd party market in addition. I would hate to run into payout issues....etc.

Comment: An example of these 3rd party markets is like http://www.androidpit.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also consider that free versions of your app (wherever they are) can point to the paid version on a select few markets (or just the main market) to consolidate your sales rather than fragment them over a bunch of markets you'll never meet the minimum for.  My paid app is on SlideMe, but I won't reach the payout threshold for a while so I can't comment on it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon's App Store sounds promising. 
https://developer.amazon.com/welcome.html

Answer (score 0):

I use [Yaam](http://yaam.mobi/) (Yet Another Android Market) in addition to the official Android Market. It allow me to do thing that cannot be possible with the official solution, like discount or special offer to a particular person, but it doesn't bring me a lot of new customers.

Also a 3rd party market owner can change the sells condition when he want, it can be a little frustrating. This is also true for Google but they pay more attention on their customers.

Comment: I had a bit of concern about uploading my apk to someone elses server where they could distribute the app behind my back.

Comment: I just signed up for the Amazon market I trust them a bit more than some of these no name markets overseas. I don't really like the $99 a year fee. (First year free) They better sell a lot of my apps or I won't be renewing!

Comment: Actually I know the guy behind Yaam, I have his personnal email and we live in the same country, so maybe this helps me to be confident :)